# How to use a state from one class to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

So i'm currently working on a PokeDex using the PokeApi available online.

The code of the project is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PokemonCard from "./PokemonCard";
import "../ui/PokemonList.css";
import axios from "axios";

export const PokemonList = class PokemonList extends Component {
  state = {
    url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/",
    pokemon: null
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await axios.get(this.state.url);
    this.setState({ pokemon: res.data["results"] });

    console.log(res);
  }

  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
};
export const PokeList = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {this.state.pokemon ? (
        <section className="poke-list">
          {this.state.pokemon.map(pokemon => (
            <PokemonCard />
          ))}
        </section>
      ) : (
        <h1>Loading Pokemon</h1>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

As you can see, I have declared a state in the PokemonList Component class, but then I try to call it further down within the variable PokeList. The issue is that the state is not being recognized in PokeList

(I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined" )

How can I go about calling the state that's declared in the class above?

-------------------EDIT-------------------------------

Okay, so I realized something. I have a code for my Dashboard.js that displays my list. Code is as follows

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { PokeList } from "../pokemon/PokemonList";

export default class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <PokeList />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I change the code from PokeList to PokemonList. so it'd be

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { PokemonList } from "../pokemon/PokemonList";

export default class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <PokemonList />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I think get a list of 20 pokemon from the Api from

console.log(this.state.pokemon);.

But since I'm not displaying PokeList on the dashboard, then none of the pokemon cards display.

Screenshot of console output

[image]

Comment: if pokemon list has only logical function you don't need it at all  or you can convert it into context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a little of confusion between your PokemonList and PokeList component. I believe that what you really are looking for is to have just one of those. If you mix the two, you can have a component that controls the view based on the state, in your case, the state is your Pokemon list.

I mixed the two here, so your render method renders "Loading Pokemon" until you get your response back from axios, then when the response is back, it gets that data, updates your state and the state update trigger a re-render.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PokemonCard from "./PokemonCard";
import axios from "axios";

class PokemonList extends Component {
  state = {
    url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/",
    pokemon: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(this.state.url).then(res => {
      this.setState({ pokemon: res.data["results"] });
    });
  }

  render() {
    let pokemonList = <h1>Loading Pokemon</h1>;

    const pokemons = this.state.pokemon;

    if (pokemons) {
      pokemonList = (
        <section className="poke-list">
          <ul>
            {pokemons.map(pokemon => (
              <PokemonCard pokemon={pokemon} />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </section>
      );
    }

    return <React.Fragment>{pokemonList}</React.Fragment>;
  }
}

export default PokemonList;
```

I also created a simple PokemonCard component where I list the result from the API, just to show you that that approach works.

```js
import React from "react";

const pokemonCard = props => {
  return (
    <li key={props.pokemon.name}>
      <a href={props.pokemon.url}>{props.pokemon.name}</a>
    </li>
  );
};

export default pokemonCard;
```

You can find the final code, with PokeList and PokemonList now combined into one component called PokemonList here:

[image: Edit shy-pine-de969]

Keep in mind that if your render function depends on a certain state, it's probably certain that you should have that state being managed in that component, or passed down from a parent component.

In your example, I noticed you set url inside your state. URL is really not something that will change. It's a constant,so you can easily remove that from your state and place it in a variable and just leave your pokemon list there.

For example:

```js
const url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";
state = {
    pokemon: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(url).then(res => {
      this.setState({ pokemon: res.data["results"] });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all functional components are stateless. If you need to maintain state use class components or hooks. You can't use the state of one component in another component, You have two options,

1. Create a parent-child relationship between those components
2. Use state management libraries(Redux, etc)

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I can go about doing either? like creating a parent-chlid relationship, or which management library I could use

Comment: In your case, PokemonList component has the state value so initiate PokeList from the PokemonList and pass the state value as props to the PokeList. 

https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: You can pass your state and setState function from parent to child component and you can access these variables as props in child component.

Comment: @Thuvarakan how could I do this? Don't really understand this concept too much as I'm new to react

Comment: Please refer to this example, states are passed from SignUpDialog to LoginInput using props.

1. https://codepen.io/thuva4/pen/bGbQaBy?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

```js
import  React , { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
//make it as class based component
export default class PokemonList extends Component {
  state = {
    url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/",
    pokemon: null
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await axios.get(this.state.url);
    this.setState({ pokemon: res.data["results"] });

    console.log(res);
  }

  render() {
    //check your data here 
     console.log(this.state.pokemon)
    {/*pass data to child*/}
    return <div> <PokeList data = { this.state } /> </div>;
  }
};

//export this component
export const PokeList = (props) => {
//check your data is coming or not
console.log(props.data)
//access your data from props
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {props.data.pokemon ? (
        <section className="poke-list">
          {props.data.pokemon.map(pokemon => (
               pokemon.name
          ))}
        </section>
      ) : (
        <h1>Loading Pokemon</h1>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: This returns the error "cannot rad property 'pokemon' of undefined" .

Comment: i hope you get props in PokeList.check your data using console.log(props) in Pokelist.please give that output

Comment: Where in the pokelist code would I add the console.log ?

Comment: yes. do console.log(props.data) in PokeList and you will gate pokemon

Comment: 1min i will change in my answer

Comment: it says "undefined" on the console log for that line of code.

Comment: please check you are getting data in your state before you pass it to child.console.log(this.state.pokemon) in your PokemonList render method

Comment: nothing is being displayed on the console still it's still facing that state error.

Comment: i will get back to you with example.

Comment: it works fine. try this and you will get data in your console.

Comment: It now says "Cannot read property 'pokemon' of undefined. But still only "undefined" is returned int he console log.

Comment: i have try this code.this give me proper console output

Comment: I copied and pasted it directly, it's not returning anything for me.

Comment: you are getting your data from api in your 
    console.log(res) ?.it might be problem with axios request.

Comment: I realized something crucial, I edited the question with further details

Answer (score 0):

You need iterate your your pokelist passing the result from your componentDidMount function to your child component as a prop , then receive your prop in the child component [here it's a working codesandbox iterating your pokemon names in the pokeList child component](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-violet-yfgf9?fontsize=14)